# Как создать корзину в Java?

Tags: java, android

Нужно создать интернет-магазин. Пользователь выбирает товары, они складываются в корзину.  Нужно создать корзину, с этим впринципе и проблема,не знаю как так сделать. Думаю, код писать смысла нет, надеюсь вопрос понятно задал.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: нет смысла спрашивать без кода. здесь не форум а база знаний, есть конкретный вопрос а  на него конкретный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем приложении буду отображаться товары которые где-то размещены, в реальном магазине или интернет-магазине, не важно. У вас будет список этих товаров и дальше вам нужно реализовать возможность добавления в корзину. Я бы вам посоветовал сделать класс-синглтон в котором будет хранится массив товаров которые в корзине. При нажатии на сам элемент списка товаров или при нажатии на какую-то специально созданную для этих нужд кнопку, вы обновляете массив который хранится в вашем синглтоне. И дальше при переходе на корзину вы запрашиваете этот массив и отображаете выбранные товары в списке. Все предельно просто, но я не исключаю варианта что кто-то предложит более достойный вариант который будет более эффективным в контексте вашей проблемы. Если будут вопросы или возникнут сложности, то не стесняйтесь и спрашивайте, постараемся помочь чем сможем. Удачи :)